# Excel shortcut to display the entire content of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there an Excel shortcut that displays the entire content of a cell (e.g. long piece of text), which is otherwise hidden as the cell size is too small?

Comment: Do you want to expand the cell to see the entire cell contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have cells with content larger than the width and want to view all the contents inline within the spreadsheet you can press <kbd>F2</kbd>. This allows you to edit the contents.

Here is an example with more text than the width of the cell.

[image: Example 1]

In this example click into `B2` and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, you can now see and edit all the contents of that cell.

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can normally see the entire formula in the **"cell edit"** field.
This is located at the top of your worksheet area and just to the right of **"*fx*"**.

Normally you can view the entire cell contents, but when it contains a lengthy formula, you can expand this field by clicking on the dropdown button, located to the right of the **"cell edit"** field.

Additionally, you can scroll through the field by using the scroll bar buttons or place your mouse over the bottom border of the field and click & drag to expand the area of the field and display the entire formula of your cell.